# Tensorflow: how to create batch with different type of data from different source (folder)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-processing

I can't find an appropriate question title, sorry.

I have a graph composed by two main data flow: image classification and label cleaning. I have two type of data:

1. (image_data, noisy_label, verified_label) from validation set
2. (image_data, noisy_label) from train set

The first is used to train the label cleaning part of the graph.
The second is used to train the image classification after its noisy label is cleaned.

Every batch need to have a ratio of 1:9.

How can i create this type of batch?? is it possible in tensorflow??

Comment: Try two queues? one reads 1, another reads 9. Then put them together to form a batch. Just an idea and I didn't think it through...

Comment: Tomorrow i will try

Comment: i created two `queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames_queue)` with two different `filenames_queue`. i created a `reader = tf.WholeFileReader()` for each `queue`. Now i think i must use `tf.train.batch([example, label], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=32)` function. But i can't create batch with ratio 1:9.

Comment: I solved the ratio problem!! I create two batch, one for validation, one for train. Then i concatenate them with `image_batch = tf.concat([image_validation_batch, image_train_batch], 0)`. This is only for image batch, i will investigate on the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the ratio problem!! I create two batch, one for validation, one for train. Then i concatenate them with `image_batch = tf.concat([image_validation_batch, image_train_batch], 0)`. This is only for image batch, i will investigate on the label.